# Displaying text from a txt file that lives on a server in a Roku Channel

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am very new to Roku BrightScript. I am trying to display a terms of use that is hosted on a server ex. (https://example.com/en-us-terms.txt)

I tried `roURLTransfer` with no success and `ReadAsciiFile`

Can someone please point me in the right direction

Thank you

Comment: Do you get any errors? Can you share the code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up a task? You will need a task that posts the result to an "m.top" field that is observed from your render thread. If you follow the example here it should get you going: https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/scenegraph/control-nodes/task.md